# Getting XSD schema file to be used automatically

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, xsd, schema

I have a library which can be configured using Custom Config Sections in `App.Config`.
Then I used `Xsd.exe` to generate a `.Xsd` file to allow Intellisense to be used when editing the `App.Config` section.
Then I added the Xsd file to the project.

Now when I reference the project from a project using the library, when I click on `XML->Schemas`, the new Xsd file automatically shows up in the list, and the Use column has no Icon, indicating `Automatic`. However no intelisense appears for the elements, if I change it to a green check mark `Use this schema` the intelisense appears.

So I have three questions:

1. How do I get intelisense to appear when it is set for `automatic`?
2. If I can't do #1, how do I automatically set `Use this schema` when the library is referenced?
3. Is there a way to add intellesense for code completion on the `configSections`, add Section portion (the part that defines that there will be a custom config section later in the config)?

Comment: have a look at Config Section Designer http://csd.codeplex.com/